# Unable to format SSD after dual booting Windows 10 with ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Its been 3 days since I failed in dual booting Windows 10 with Ubuntu

I didnt know much about dual booting and just followed a few tutorials and when I installed ubuntu I chose the option " install alongside  with windows"

Now my windows is in the automatic repair loop everytime I turn it on. I can boot into ubuntu when I press "ESC" when I turn it on then F9 for boot options then choosing ubuntu.

And I did a lot of things like rebuilding the bcd and everything but I keep failing for a variety of reasons. Now I decided to install a fresh windows 10 but I failed to format.
I think maybe this is because my original windows partition is now in the RAW format and I also fail to format it in cmd
Really need help

Im using an HP-Omen with ssd(OS is located) and hdd( most of my usual files)
[Error in formating][1]

When using cmd and diskpart these are the following Volumes and partitions [diskpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCt6L.jpg!%5Bdiskpart%5D)

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSz1F.jpg![unable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSz1F.jpg!%5Bunable) to Format]

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCt6L.jpg![Trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCt6L.jpg!%5BTrying) to delete the partition]

Comment: Why don’t you just delete the existing partitions then install Windows on the unallocated space?

Comment: I cannot also delete the partition and install on the partition and weirdly it has free space

Comment: It should be impossible for it to be “not possible” to delete a partition within WinRE can you provide more information?

Comment: Im sorry Im currently using a phone now to troubleshoot , I just a bought a USB since  I've been using a external hard drive to reinstall windows I'll add more details and pictures

Answer (score 0):

First open cmd from the windows installation by using this tutorial :https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-start-command-prompt-when-windows-doesnt-boot/

After opening cmd we will use diskpart to format windows partition (c drive )

1.Type `diskpart`

2.Type `list disk`

3.Now type `select disk(and your desired drive number)`

4.Then type `list partition`

5.Then type `select partition (partition number)`

6.Type `clean` to format the drive

7.Type `create partition primary` to make it usable

6.To format disk to NTFS type `format fs=ntfs`

9.Then we need to assign a drive letter to it so type`assign`

All done

Then try to install windows in this newly formatted drive
.Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this but Diskpart has encountered and error I'll post the image in my question

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't post more images in my question but after doing what ypu said I have 4 partitions which are System, Reserved, Primary and Recovery

Comment: I tried cleaning the primary buy diskpart has encountered an error: Incorrect Function , see the system event Log for more information

Comment: You can clean the whole disk (ubuntu include). By above-mentioned method by skipping the 4th and 5th step .And check if it helps.

Comment: Tried that also but Diskparted still encountered an error: Incorrect Function . According to what Ive searched online my ssd is write protected and im trying to change it in order for me to use the chkdsk commands but still I get errors in changing its attributes. Also I can still boot ubuntu so i think my ssd is not dead

Comment: You can try this article https://www.diskpart.com/articles/ssd-write-protected-1984.html and let me know if it helps

Comment: And I have installed ubuntu by manually creating  free space not by the option "install alongside with windows" and it work perfectly fine

Comment: Unfortunately ubuntu didint boot anymore and finally I decided to remove my ssd and installed Windows 10 on my hdd instead and repair the ssd through 3rd party softwares. I thank you for the suggestion really appreciate it!